# Auto complete address input

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the Google auto complete address search script.

So when a user enters an address, the input auto poplulates with search results. At the moment this shows addresses across the word, but I only need UK address

```
Script:
  <script>


      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }



    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Is there a way to limit this to the UK only?

Comment: @George - Thanks, but I'm not sure where the code snippet goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this function, the only change is in the options you're passing to the Autocomplete by adding a Component Restriction

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {
        types: ['geocode'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "uk" }
    });

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
```